# Delaying the Initiation of MonoBehaviours

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to initiate my GameManager with data, which is provieded by the LevelLoader. The problem is that some Behaviours need to access some of this data themself on Initation and there are already present, when the scene loads, meaning I'll get a NullReference because the GameManager isn't initiated yet.

```
class LevelLoader
{
    void LoadLevel()
    {
        // ...
        
        // Initiate Game Manager
        GameManager.Instance.Initiate(data);
        
    }
}
```

---

```
class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ...
    
    public int someNum;
    
    public void Initiate(data)
    {
        // ...
        // This action may take a cuple of frames
        // ...
        
        someNum = data.someNum;
    }
}
```

---

```
class SomeSceneObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {   
        // Initiate SomeSceneObject
        DoSomething(GameManager.Instance.someNum);
    }
}
```

**Option 1:**

I was thinking about adding an Interface for any script that requires the GameManager on Setup, which will replace the default Awake and Start methods:

```
interface IStartable
{
    void Awake2();
    void Start2();
}
```

But than I would also have to override the Update method, because it needs to be suppressed until Awake2 and Start2 are called. Which would make this solution even more ugly.

```
interface IStartable
{
    void Awake2();
    void Start2();
    void Update2();
    void LateUpdate();
    void FixedUpdate();
}
```

**Option 2:**

I was also thinking about moving my initiation code to the Start method and disabling all scripts before there are called and reactivating them when ready.

But than I would have to keep track on all objects I need to disable on my GameManager/LevelLoader Script, which would be even more ugly and difficult to maintain.

**Option 2b:**

I could also add an Initiate() method to SomeSceneObject and call it when the GameManager is done instead of using Awake() but same problem: I need to keep track of all MonoBehaviours how need to be called on the GameManager which isn't ideal.

**Question:**

How do I delay the iniation and keep it maintainalbe?

Comment: Have you considered using Zenject for DI, IoC container? You would have a clear initialization and simple extensibility during the development. Here is a boilerplate project with Zenject installed. https://github.com/Ar11rA/AllThingsZen

Comment: My thumbrule: initialize yourself in `Awake` where you don't need access to others. Then in `Start` do stuff where you need others already initialized. Where this isn't enough you can still play around with the [script execution order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) or use a more complex initialization event system

Comment: Well. You could make gamemanager first.

Comment: @BugFinder Like I said, the components are already in the scene when it's loaded. And as far as I understand Unity does the Awake, Start, ... code before continuing with the LevelLoader Code, so there is no time to "make the gamemanager first"

Comment: @derHugo I'd normaly do the same, but in this case waiting for Start isn't enough. I could wait in Update until the GM is ready as a budget solution, but I find this kinda ugly tbo.

Comment: @VisDesignThe git isn't documented at all. Could you give me a brief idea what it's about?

Comment: As said in that case go for events .. in awake you can hook up listeners to events like `Initialized` or whatever and then do your own initialization .. of course you will need to implement some kind of dependency checks to detect circular dependencies ...

Comment: If game manager is made in the start menu. Or game manager is the first object of the scene it is first.